# Why has log4j-slf4j-impl no dependency on log4j-core when using Slf4j over Log4j2

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I want to use log4j2 as the logging implementation for my slf4j logging application.

[The documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) states i have to depend on log4j-slf4j-impl and on log4j-core.

My question is why log4j-slf4j-impl has no dependency on log4j-core ( and thus brings with it the library it definitely needs)?

Comment: can you provide a bit more information your context? maybe provide some info about your app, your dependencies or even your pom?

Comment: My question is not project specific. It is about why the developers of log4j2 chose to force me to put 2 dependencies in my pom, if i clearly only need one, namely `log4j-slf4j-impl`. The `log4j-core` dependency is , imo, implied by that, and i wonder why they choose to build like that.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the SLF4J bridge only requires the Log4j 2 API. You could build your own implementation of the Log4j 2 API and include that instead of the Log4j 2 core jar.

If you wonder why the developers chose to build it like that wouldn't you think you would be more likely to get an accurate answer if you asked on the log4j developers mailing list?

Comment: The point is, when i chose log4j-slf4j-**impl** then i already chose my logging _implementation_ (and implicitly slf4j as interface) . Indirecting again would mean providing an implementation for the implementation. I agree, this is hairsplitting.

Comment: I chose stackoverflow over the developer-mailing-list as i thought it might be the more publicly accessible place.

Comment: By choosing `log4j-slf4j-impl` you're choosing the SLF4J bridge implementation; not log4j implementation. `log4j-slf4j-impl` can apparently work with anything that implements Log4j 2 API. That's why it is not bound to a specific impl.